# Error validating webhook configuration yaml file when trying to setup OPA, using minikube

Tags: kubernetes, devops, minikube, opa

I am trying to setup OPA inside a minikube cluster.
After deploying the admission-controller, i am trying to setup the webhook configuration, but failing to validate the yaml.

*Below is my Yaml code* :

```
apiVersion: admissionregistration.k8s.io/v1
kind: ValidatingWebhookConfiguration
metadata:
  name: opa-validating-webhook
webhooks:
  - name: validating-webhook.openpolicyagent.org
    namespaceSelector:
      matchExpressions:
      - key: openpolicyagent.org/webhook
        operator: NotIn
        values:
        - ignore
    rules:
      - operations: ["CREATE", "UPDATE"]
        apiGroups: ["*"]
        apiVersions: ["*"]
        resources: ["*"]
    clientConfig:
      caBundle: $(cat ca.crt | base64 | tr -d '\n')
      service:
        namespace: opa
        name: opa
    admissionReviewVersions: ["v1"]
    sideEffects: None
```

*Below is the error* i am facing....

error when creating "admission-webhook.yaml": ValidatingWebhookConfiguration in version "v1" cannot be handled as a ValidatingWebhookConfiguration: illegal base64 data at input byte 0

Answer (score 0):

Do you expand the `caBundle` field's value before running `kubectl` on the `yaml` file? If not that might be the error.

To solve it, you can run `$(cat ca.crt | base64 | tr -d '\n')` in a shell and then cut and paste the standard output value to the `caBundle` field's value in the `yaml`. And then run `kubectl` on the update yaml file.